# jQuery Animation Delay Adding A Class

Tags: jquery, animation

I am trying to delay the adding of a class using jquery. All the code works fine but I would like to delay the `.addClass('hideText')` until after the hover out function completes could someone show me how to do this please?

Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.listing div').addClass('hideText');

$('.listing div').hover(

function() {
    $(this)
    .stop(true)
    .removeClass('hideText')
    .animate(
        {top: '0'},
        {duration: 300, easing: 'linear', queue: false}
    )
    },
    function() {
        $(this)
        .stop(true)
        .animate(
            {top: '150px'},
            {duration: 300, easing: 'linear', queue: false}
        )
        .addClass('hideText')
    });
```

});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place the `.addClass()` line in a callback:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('.listing div').addClass('hideText');

$('.listing div').hover(

function() {
    $(this)
    .stop(true)
    .removeClass('hideText')
    .animate(
        {top: '0'},
        {duration: 300, easing: 'linear', queue: false}
    )
    },
    function() {
        $(this)
        .stop(true)
        .animate(
            {top: '150px'},
            {duration: 300, easing: 'linear', queue: false},
            function() {
                 $(this).addClass('hideText');
            }
        );
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the help, unfortunately that didn't work. The .listing div still animates up and down fine, and the .hideText class gets added and taken off initially but doesn't get added after the animation completes.

Comment: Please provide a link to an example.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried queueing the function like this?

```
    function() {
        $(this).stop(true).queue(function (next) {
            .animate(
                {top: '150px'},
                {duration: 300, easing: 'linear', queue: false},
            next();
        })
        function() {
            $(this).addClass('hideText');
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hi Keith. Sorry this was such a long time ago now I have forgot how I solved it. Thank you for taking the time to answer though.